# System.out.format questions. %d%n

Tags: java

It keeps giving me an error. 
I am confused with the %d%n part. can anyone explain to me??
I want the amount of money to show up.
Thank you

```
System.out.println("Thank you for choosing withdrawl.");
System.out.println("How much would u like to withdrawl?");
System.out.println("1=100");
System.out.println("2=200");
System.out.println("3=300");
System.out.println("4=400");
System.out.println("5=500");
withdrawlmoney = user.nextInt();
switch(withdrawlmoney){
    case 1:  withdrawlmoneynumber = "100";
        break;
    case 2:  withdrawlmoneynumber = "200";
        break;
    case 3:  withdrawlmoneynumber = "300";
        break;
    case 4:  withdrawlmoneynumber = "400";
        break;
    case 5:  withdrawlmoneynumber = "500";
        break;
    default: withdrawlmoneynumber = "Invalid amount";
        break;
}
System.out.println(withdrawlmoneynumber);
System.out.format("the value you want to withdrawl is: %d%n" , withdrawlmoneynumber);
```

Comment: It doesnt give me an error when i compile the code. But When i run it, weird messages pop up

Comment: It still doesnt work. It says java.util.IllegalFormatConversionExeption; d != java.lang.string

Comment: An aside, in your plain text strings: *"the value you want to withdrawl"* - remove the "l" at the end of "withdrawl" - that's the verb form. And change all "withdrawl" to "withdrawal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try...

```
 System.out.format("the value you want to withdrawl is: %s\n" , withdrawlmoneynumber);
```

withdrawlmoneynumber is string..

> the format should be %s

for string according to [Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

I am guessing you meant for the %n to be \n indicating a new-line

Answer (score 8):

The format code `"%d"` means print a decimal number. But you are passing a `String`. The data type of `withdrawalmoneynumber` should be numeric.

The format code `"%n"` means print a line separator, which is platform dependent. It might be `"\n"`, `"\r\n"`, or `"\r"` depending where the code is run.

Comment: It would be useful if you specify how to use a String instead.

Comment: I have in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do it:

```
System.out.println("The value you want to withdrawl is: " + withdrawlmoneynumber);
```

This will work for any data type.